# Why is POISSON function not consistent in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

There is a definition in `POISSON` function that:

`#NUM!` error – Occurs if either:

- The given value of x is less than zero;
- The given value of mean is
  less than zero.

But I try to do this in Excel 2013. It gave me differnt value. Here is my example:

```
=POISSON(0,-0.5,FALSE)
```

the result is: `1.648721271`
instead of `#NUM!`

Any thoughts?

Comment: I Get the same result in Excel 2016. Actually it only happens for `x = 0` and `mean < 0`

Comment: It is a bug. The only answer to your question why is that programmers make mistakes, which sometimes slip through to production code. It is somewhat speculative to say anything more.

Comment: Still, it is fun to speculate (see below) and this question serves a good purpose of alerting others about a potentially serious bug.

Answer (score 1):

Speculatively, the bug might have come about as an optimization. `Poisson(x,m,TRUE)` is defined as `e^(-m)*(m^x)/x!`. One way to compute `m^x` when `m` is floating-point is as `e^(x*Ln(m))`. In a spreadsheet, you can observe that

```
=POISSON(A1,A2,TRUE) - EXP(-A2)*EXP(A1*LN(A2))/FACT(A1)
```

always evaluates to exactly 0 whenever `A1,A2` are in the correct domain (and not e.g. 0.0000000001 as might be the case if the calculation had used a different approach).
Furthermore, `EXP(-A2)*EXP(A1*LN(A2))/FACT(A1)` fails when it should fail, giving `#NUM!` when fed `0, -0.5`. My speculation is that the Excel programmers initially used a formula which failed when it should have failed, letting the called functions raise the error when appropriate. Then someone had the bright idea of just returning `EXP(-mean)` when `x = 0` (since in that case the rest of the expression is 1 *when it is defined at all*). After all -- why bother to compute something when you know that it is 1?

What I find astonishing is that the bug is still there with `POISSON.DIST` Excel had been (and still is, although to a lesser extent) heavily criticized for the accuracy of its statistical functions and tests. So much so that "Friends don't let friends use Excel for statistics" is a relatively well-known saying among statisticians. See [this](http://statisticalengineering.com/Weibull/excel.html) for a discussion. The dotted statistical functions such as `POISSON.DIST` were explicitly designed to address the many complaints which had piled up. `POISSON` itself is just kept around for backwards compatibility. It is strange how this bug slipped through what should have been a thorough rewriting of these functions from the ground up.

Comment: Nice research. So still no test-driven development at Microsoft ^^ (or no test for the defined rules in the help file).